# nginx configuration file : server, server_name and upstream understanding

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have this nginx.conf configuration file inherited from a github project and i'd like some people to explain me what is doing what:

```
upstream hello_django {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name react-wagtail-api.accordbox.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hello_django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /app/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name react-wagtail.accordbox.com;
    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html/build;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

with

```
upstream hello_django {
        server web:8000;
    }
```

is `web` a service (elswhere there is a docker-compose container name which is `web`... is it a ref to that? ) ?
What does `upstream` define exactly?

with

```
server_name react-wagtail-api.accordbox.com;
```

what happens if i dont define a `server_name` for example in case i dont have yet a domain? is server_name the domain typed in the adress bar of the browser? can i define it as the local ip and let my domain name provider do the redirect? can i define it as the internet ip of the server and let my domain name provider do the redirect?

As there are two servers on the same port, can i define for example `server_name my_internet_ip/app1` and `server_name my_internet_ip/app2` to serve two servers on port 80?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is `web` a service (elsewhere there is a docker-compose container name which is `web`... is it a ref to that?)

Generally, `web` here is an upstream domain name (can be also specified via IP address or UNIX socket path). However, when this is executed within the docker-compose context, at the nginx startup time it will be resolved to the `web` container internal IP using docker internal domain name resolving system.

> What does `upstream` define exactly?

For this particular configuration, there will be no difference using either

```
upstream hello_django {
    server web:8000;
}
server {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://hello_django;
```

or specifying an upstream address directly in the `proxy_pass` directive:

```
server {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://web:8000;
```

Really useful `upstream` use cases include failover ([example](https://serverfault.com/questions/480241/nginx-failover-without-load-balancing)) or load balancing ([example](https://serverfault.com/questions/140990/nginx-automatic-failover-load-balancing)). Read the [`ngx_http_upstream_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) documentation to find out all the available features.

> What happens if i don't define a `server_name` for example in case i don't have yet a domain?

To understand this part make sure you read the following two chapters from the official documentation:

- [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)
- [Server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

You can omit the `server_name` directive from the server block at all. For any HTTP request arriving at the TCP port where nginx is listening, one of the defined `server` blocks (usually the very first one appearing in the configuration, unless being specified explicitly using `default_server` parameter of `listen` directive) will act as the default server if more appropriate server block won't be found. The [`Host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) HTTP request header value is used to choose the most suitable server block here, being compared with the specified `server_name` for the server block, and it will be exactly what you typed at the browser address bar (assuming IP address/domain name being typed will actually point to the nginx server). That means there is no sense to specify the same server name for different server blocks listening on the same TCP ports - the first one will always be chosen to process such a request, and the nginx will complain with the

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "..." on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

warning message. For the developing purposes you can add the required domain names to the [`hosts`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) system file, pointing them to your local machine, e.g.

```
127.0.0.1  react-wagtail.accordbox.com
127.0.0.1  react-wagtail-api.accordbox.com
```

This way you will be able to use those domains from your local browser, the generated HTTP requests will contain the proper `Host` header and will be processed with your local nginx server instance.

> As there are two servers on the same port, can i define for example `server_name my_internet_ip/app1` and `server_name my_internet_ip/app2` to serve two servers on port 80?

No. Looks like you don't understand the internals of HTTP protocol. At the low level HTTP request will be something like

```
GET /app1 HTTP/1.1
Host: my_internet_ip
...
```

As you can see the host name and the request URL path are two completely different things. Usually this kind of tasks being solved using several location blocks:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    location /app1/ {
        ...
    }
    location /app2/ {
        ...
    }
}
```

However it will require support from the underlying web apps. Two available options are

- Referring assets using relative URIs, e.g.

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  ```

  or

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
  ```

  but not the using absolute URIs like

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
  ```
- Using the same URI prefix as specified in the `location` directive, e.g.

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app1/style.css">
  ```

The reason should be obvious - every request for any first or second app assets should start with the `/app1/` or `/app2/` prefix for being handled with the proper location block.

As you can see, I'm using `/app1/` and `/app2/` suffixes here rather than `/app1` and `/app2`. This is a very common mistake made by many people, to not understand the difference between those two. While it may seems to be an insignificant, in fact those two are drastically different in terms of [**browsing context**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Browsing_context) which will be `/` in first case and `/app1/` or `/app2/` in second case. Unless you are proxying some kind of API endpoint but a whole web application, you probably want the second one. To make it more easy, a [`location`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) directive special behavior provided by nginx:

> If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash character, and requests are processed by one of `proxy_pass`, `fastcgi_pass`, `uwsgi_pass`, `scgi_pass`, `memcached_pass`, or `grpc_pass`, then the special processing is performed. In response to a request with URI equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with the slash appended. If this is not desired, an exact match of the URI and location could be defined like this:
>
> ```
> location /user/ {
>     proxy_pass http://user.example.com;
> }
>
> location = /user {
>     proxy_pass http://login.example.com;
> }
> ```

Although we can override the browsing context using the [`<base href="...">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) HTML tag, I strongly recommend to not use this workaround and use a proper URI prefixes for your proxied web apps instead.

Comment: i ve tested locally my containers and nginx cant resolve web even if web is the name of the container...how can i tell nginx the ip of my container?

Comment: Using container names is a common practice, it works everywhere, and I don't think the container IP is a static thing or can be determined before the container is started. What makes you sure it is nginx can't resolve your container name to IP address? You'd better post it as a separate question including both nginx configuration and `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

`web` service in your case resolves to some IP, same with `server_name`. You can read more about upstreams [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html), same for [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) directive.

Comment: ok thank you! but the way nginx is referring to web (which has an ip) is by the service name, right?