# nginx : two servers on port 80 with different locations not serving

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx conf file like this :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html/build;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location /wagtail {
        proxy_pass http://172.20.128.2:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /app/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media/;
    }
}
```

When i go to localhost:80/wagtail, i get the error from the first server that it cant resolve. From the nginx doc, i understood i can serve on the same port provided the server_name is different and in case it's the same, the default server is the first in the list.

But what about locations? how can i tweak the config file so the second server works?

it's because it's a blog with a frontend serving on port 80 and administration serving on port 8000. i would like the user to access both on port 80 at the same adress with a /admin location for the administration

Comment: This is absolutely different from what you were asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72422223/nginx-configuration-file-server-server-name-and-upstream-understanding/72422831?noredirect=1#comment127953639_72422831). The `localhost` domain name inside the docker-compose environment makes no sense and cannot be resolved to any container IP. I'm not sure what `172.20.128.2` means here, whatever it is, most likely it should be changed to some container name. I don't see anything named `web` here, as you've mentioned in your question.

Comment: Using two server blocks listening on the same ports with the same server name is completely senseless. Moreover, it means you didn't understand my explanations from your previous question at all. Didn't you notice `nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored` warning from nginx? The second server block will never serve any request at all.

Comment: i've dodged the container name issue with resolving the container ip...
regarding the two server with the same name : it's because it's a blog with a frontend serving on port 80 and administration serving on port 8000. i would like the user to access both on port 80 at the same adress with a /admin location for the administration

Comment: You don't need to use direct IPs instead of container names, if you can't make it work without doing it, most likely you are doing something in a completely wrong way. What you are asking for usually solved using `location /admin/ { proxy_pass http://<container_name>:8000; ... }`. I added some information to my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72422831/7121513) answer.

Comment: so after testing your answer, it's not working, the page shows "not found" at /admin... can there be a conflict with the wagtail registered urls?

Answer (score 0):

so, in case your servername is identical, try using this code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html/build;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location /wagtail {
        proxy_pass http://172.20.128.2:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /app/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media/;
    }
}
```

it combines both server blocks